# Swift 4 How can I get the first 30 of a string

Tags: swift, substring, swift4

I have just updated to Swift 4 and I am finding it difficult to show the first 30 characters of a string. I have a TableView that gets data via Json and that is populating a label. Now since Substrings can not be used anymore I am having a hard time getting this to work. I am essentially checking if the string returned has 30 or more characters and if it does then I want to show only those 30 characters else show everything since it's under 30 characters .... This is my code

```
 if streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row].count >= 30
       {
        // Show 30 characters here
        cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]   
       //.substringFromIndex(cell.post.text.endIndex.advancedBy(-4))

        }
        else
       {
        cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
        }
        cell.post.tag = indexPath.row
```

Comment: The duplicate works also with *first*: `String(streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row].prefix(30))`

Comment: If this is not longer a duplicate then you need to explain why it is different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prefix`:

```
cell.post.text = String(streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row].prefix(30))
```